# Use Hibernate entities only on test classpath in Quarkus

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing, quarkus, bootstrapping

I have a project that will do plain, rather generic SQL in the main code for merging two equivalent tenant databases (e.g. having the same schema but different data). I want to be able to test this application and generate schema's and data in the (unit) tests and use Hibernate for that, so I create a mini JPA model in `src/test/java/entities`, but when I run `quarkus dev`, Hibernate complains that it is disabled because it can't find any entities:

```
WARN  [io.qua.hib.orm.dep.HibernateOrmProcessor] (build-27) Hibernate ORM is disabled because no JPA entities were found
```

I don't want to pollute my application with these model classes that exist purely for testing purposes. Is there a way to bind the Hibernate bootstrap to the test class path?

Searching for the usual terms (e.g. `hibernate quarkus test class path`) give no relevant results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quarkus `dev mode` doesn't use any of files under `src/test`.
If you want to have entities and Hibernate available only during test just add `<scope>test</scope>` to `io.quarkus:quarkus-hibernate-orm` dependency in pom.xml and all should be solved.

Comment: Many thanks! This is so obvious, yet so unobvious a fix.